# Wifi over USB - Is there a common class driver?

Tags: usb, wifi, driver

Is there a predefined class driver for Wifi over USB for WiFi dongles. I know today several vendors offer WiFi dongles and you end up installing drivers which may indicate the lack of standard class driver however. I also suspect there may be a common class driver however vendors nonetheless provide a custom driver for features not covered in the common class driver. There is one for ethernet, therefore the reasonable assumption is there must be one for WiFi.

If not, is there any similarity among vendors that is sufficiently large enough that you can make a driver where you can move from one vendor to the next with ease?

Bonus question: Is there any open source, RTOS version (Any RTOS is fine) of such drivers available? I have been looking with not much success.

Comment: I must be being dense - but how do you do wireless over a wire? Do you mean USB protocol over a wireless link? Can you ne more precise in your question please? More context is good.

Comment: @preet sangha improved.. thx.

Comment: Of course he should be talking about a Wifi device connected to the computer thru an USB connection.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a predefined class driver for Wifi over USB?

No. USB is just the protocol used to connect the device to your machine. The protocol used to communicated with the device, depends on the device itself.

> If not, is there any similarity among vendors that is sufficiently
>   large enough that you can make a driver where you can move from one
>   vendor to the next with ease?

I really don't think so.

Comment: @overbose not that simple.. Mass storage is a class driver and the protocol is not dependent on the vendor. You cannot just assume that about USB.

Comment: @Frank: I wanted to say that the wifi device protocol is vendor's dependent.